# how can i display all the dialog parameters of all blocks in matlab?

Tags: object, parameters, dialog

my intention is to compare 2 version of a simulink model programmatically by comparing the respective blocks in each model.  get_param(blockpath,'DialogParameters) didnt work for me. is there any other way to display all the dialog parameters of all blocks?